# Finding the lowest sum of values in a list to form a target factor

Tags: algorithm, sum

I'm stuck as to how to make an algorithm to find a combination of elements from a list where the sum of those factors is the lowest possible where the factor of those numbers is a predetermined target value.

For instance a list:

```
(2,5,7,6,8,2,3)
```

And a target value:

```
12
```

Would result in these factors:

```
(2,2,3) and (2,6)
```

But the optimal combination would be:

```
(2,2,3)
```

As it has a lower sum

Comment: This sounds like an Euler problem :)

Comment: Euler problem? Just some context, I'm trying to maximize my score on a maths game.

Comment: Yeah Euler problem's are a math game. You should check them out.

Comment: How big of a list do you have to deal with? How big of a target value do you have to deal with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First erase from the list all numbers that aren't factors of `n`. So in your example your list would reduce to `(2, 6, 2, 3)`. Then I would sort the list. So you have `(2, 2, 3, 6)`. Start multiplying the elements from the left to right if you reach n stop. If you exceed n find the next smallest permutation of your numbers and repeat. This will be `(2, 2, 6, 3)` (for a C++ function that finds the next permutation see [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/)). This will guarantee to find the multiplication with the smallest sum because the we are checking the products in order from smallest sum to largest. This runs in the size of your list factorial but I think that is as good as you're going to get. This problem sounds NP hard.

You can do slightly better by pruning the permutations. Lets say you were looking for 24 and your list is (2, 4, 8, 12). The only subset is (2, 12). But the next permutation will be (2, 4, 12, 8) which you don't even need to generate because you knew that 2*4 was too small and 2*4*8 was too big and swapping 12 with 8 only increased 2*4*8. This way you didn't have to test that permutation.

Comment: After a lot of time researching and reading your insight I came up with a recursive way to do this, I will leave it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to break the problem down recursively. You have a multiset of potential factors `S = {n_1, n_2, ..., n_k}`.  Let `f(S,n)` be the maximum sum `n_i_1 + n_i_2 + ... + n_i_j` where `n_i_l` are distinct elements of the multiset and `n_i_1 * ... * n_i_j = n`. Then `f(S,n) = max_i { (n_i + f(S-{n_i},n/n_i)) where n_i divides n }`. In other words, `f(S,n)` can be computed recursively. With a little more work you can get the algorithm to spit out the actual `n_i`s that work. The time complexity could be bad, but you don't say what your goals are in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

```
def primes(n):
    primfac = []
    d = 2
    while d*d <= n:
        while (n % d) == 0:
            primfac.append(d)  # supposing you want multiple factors repeated
            n //= d
        d += 1
    if n > 1:
       primfac.append(n)
    return primfac

def get_factors_list(dividend, ceiling = float('infinity')):
    """ Yield all lists of factors where the largest is no larger than ceiling """
    for divisor in range(min(ceiling, dividend - 1), 1, -1):
        quotient, mod = divmod(dividend, divisor)
        if mod == 0:
            if quotient <= divisor:
                yield [divisor, quotient]
            for factors in get_factors_list(quotient, divisor):
                yield [divisor] + factors

def print_factors(x):
    factorList = []
    if x > 0:
        for factors in get_factors_list(x):
            factorList.append(list(map(int, factors)))
    return factorList
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's is how you could do it in Haskell:

```
import Data.List(sortBy, subsequences)
import Data.Function(on)

lowestSumTargetFactor :: (Ord b, Num b) => [b] -> b -> [b]
lowestSumTargetFactor xs target = do
    let l =  filter (/= []) $ sortBy (compare `on` sum) 
            [x | x <- subsequences xs, product x == target]
    if l == []
        then error $ "lowestSumTargetFactor: " ++ 
            "no subsequence product equals target."
        else head l
```

Here's what is happening:

`[x | x <- subsequences xs, product x == target]` builds a list made of all subsequences of the list `xs` whose product equals `target`. In your example, it would build the list `[[2,6],[6,2],[2,2,3]]`.

Then the `sortBy (compare`on`sum)` part sorts that list of list by the sum of it's list elements. It would return the list `[[2,2,3],[2,6],[6,2]]`.

I then `filter` that list, removing any `[]` elements because `product []` returns 1 (don't know the reasoning for this, yet). This was done because `lowestSumTargetFactor [1, 1, 1] 1` would return `[]` instead of the expected `[1]`.

Then I ask if the list we built is `[]`. If no, I use the function `head` to return the first element of that list (`[2,2,3]` in your case). If yes, it returns the error as written.

Obs1: where it appears above, the `$` just means that everything after it is enclosed in parentheses.

Obs2: the `lowestSumTargetFactor :: (Ord b, Num b) => [b] -> b -> [b]` part is just the function's type signature. It means that the function takes a list made of `b`s, a second argument `b` and returns another list made of `b`s, `b` being a member of both the `Ord` class of totally ordered datatypes, and the `Num` class, the basic numeric class.

Obs3: I'm still a beginner. A more experienced programmer would probably do this much more efficiently and elegantly.